# Best way to work with list of objects on Http Patch

Tags: c#, .net, api, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api

in my scenario I have a web client and an rest api (.NET Core) in web client has a page that list all Clients, in this list the user can select many Clients and mark them as Enabled.
How can I treat that "Mark as Enable" in my api?
I can update one by one on method PATCH, but with list I don't  know how.

```
public IActionResult Patch( long id, [FromBody] JsonPatchDocument<Client> patch )
{
    var client = base.DataContext.Clients.Find( id );

    if( client != null )
        patch.ApplyTo( client, ModelState );

    return Ok();
}

public class Client
{
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public string Description { get; set; }

    public bool Enabled { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: hi Luis, you will find a lot of help here but right now your question is too general, first you need to show what you have tried, what specific problem you are hitting that you've been unable to find an answer to

Answer (score 2):

The `HttpPatch` action of patching List is same as Object.

```
        [HttpPatch]
        public IActionResult JsonPatchForClients([FromBody] JsonPatchDocument<List<Client>> patchDoc)
        {
            var clients = CreateClients();

            patchDoc.ApplyTo(clients);

            return new ObjectResult(clients);
        }

        private List<Client> CreateClients()
        {
            return  new List<Client>()
            {
                    new Client
                    {
                        Name = "Client0",
                        Description = "Description0",
                        Enabled = true
                    },
                    new Client
                    {
                        Name = "Client1",
                        Description = "Description1",
                        Enabled = true
                    },
                    new Client
                    {
                        Name = "Client2",
                        Description = "Description2",
                        Enabled = true
                    }
            };
        }

        public class Client
        {
            public string Name { get; set; }

            public string Description { get; set; }

            public bool Enabled { get; set; }
        }
```

Next, I will detail how to send `Patch` Body.

Here is the raw list:

```
[
    {
        "name": "Client0",
        "description": "Description0",
        "enabled": true
    },
    {
        "name": "Client1",
        "description": "Description1",
        "enabled": true
    },
    {
        "name": "Client2",
        "description": "Description2",
        "enabled": true
    }
]
```

**1.Add** to the end of an array of "`/-`" and add to the first of an array of "`/0`"

```
    [
      {
        "op": "add",
        "path": "/-",
        "value": {
          "name": "Order3",
          "description": "Description3",
          "enabled": true
        }
      }
    ]
```

Result:

```
[
    {
        "name": "Client0",
        "description": "Description0",
        "enabled": true
    },
    {
        "name": "Client1",
        "description": "Description1",
        "enabled": true
    },
    {
        "name": "Client2",
        "description": "Description2",
        "enabled": true
    },
    {
        "name": "Order3",
        "description": "Description3",
        "enabled": true
    }
]
```

**2. Replace** `Order3` to `Order0`

```
[
  {
    "op": "replace",
    "path": "/0",
    "value": {
      "name": "Order3",
      "description": "Description3",
      "enabled": true
    }
  }
]
```

Result:

```
[
    {
        "name": "Order3",
        "description": "Description3",
        "enabled": true
    },
    {
        "name": "Client1",
        "description": "Description1",
        "enabled": true
    },
    {
        "name": "Client2",
        "description": "Description2",
        "enabled": true
    }
]
```

**3.Remve** `Client0`

```
[
  {
    "op": "remove",
    "path": "/0"
  }
]
```

Result:

```
[
    {
        "name": "Client1",
        "description": "Description1",
        "enabled": true
    },
    {
        "name": "Client2",
        "description": "Description2",
        "enabled": true
    }
]
```

4. The others(`move`,`copy`,`test`) you can find in the [microsoft doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/web-api/jsonpatch?view=aspnetcore-3.1).

Comment: But this is the order of array "path": "/0", if orders change I will update a wrong item.
My page will have to know the a item position of my list, but this list came from DB and will be sorted, filtred and so on.

Comment: There is no way to select an element from an array by some property. For updating list of object , you should considering give up JsonPatch.  JSONPatch is designed for 
 updating documents on an API in a very explicit way.

Comment: Hi,
Any examples, ideas, on how to implement Patch for a list of objects? (eg.: approving / updating a status for multiple users at once, by getting the db users by the ids from the path)

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

The another way is `replace` all.

```
    [HttpPatch]
    public IActionResult JsonPatchForClients([FromBody] JsonPatchDocument  patchDoc)
    {
        var clients = new Clients();
        patchDoc.ApplyTo(clients);

        return new ObjectResult(clients);
    }

    public class Clients
    {
        public List<Client> clients { get; set; }
        public Clients()
        {
           clients = new List<Client>()
            {
                new Client
                {
                    Name = "Client0",
                    Description = "Description0",
                    Enabled = true
                },
                new Client
                {
                    Name = "Client1",
                    Description = "Description1",
                    Enabled = true
                },
                new Client
                {
                    Name = "Client2",
                    Description = "Description2",
                    Enabled = true
                }
        };
    }
    }
```

The body of JSONPatch:

```
 [
      {
        "op": "replace",
        "path": "/clients",
        "value": [
          {
          "name": "clients1",
          "description": "Desc1",
          "enabled": false
        },{
          "name": "clients2",
          "description": "Desc2",
          "enabled": false
        }
        ]
      }
    ]
```

In this way, we can update each object of list. But it's very similar as normal way(passing models to action).
[image]

Comment: Hi Luis, have you tried to replace all? Meanwhile, I don't think HTTP PATCH is good way to update list object in your case. HTTP PUT vs HTTP PATCH see from here https://www.baeldung.com/http-put-patch-difference-spring

Comment: If insist HTTP PATCH, try patch one by one but not list.